# ¿Como iterar la hora de un DateTime en C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker

Como puedo ir iterando la hora de un DateTime.

```
DateTime horaseleccionada = Convert.ToDateTime("10:00:00");

DateTime horactual = horaseleccionada;

for (int i = 0; i < llegada.Length; i++)
{
    DateTime horaconvertida = horactual.AddMinutes(llegada[i]);
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = horaconvertida.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    horaseleccionada = horaconvertida;
}
```

La primera vez la hora tiene un valor de las **`10:00:00`** pero una vez que entra al array esta *suma 30 minutos* que es igual a **`10:30:00`**.
Necesito saber como puedo hacer que el valor de `horaseleccionada` ahora sea **`10:30:00`**.
Espero me haya dado a entender, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para iterar en un rango de fechas se usa el `while`

```
DateTime horainicio = Convert.ToDateTime("10:00:00");

DateTime horafil = llegada;

int i = 0;
while (horainicio < llegada)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = horainicio.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    horainicio = horainicio.AddMinutes(30);
    i++;
}
```

como veras en cada iteracion se va sumando los 30 min hasta llegar a la fecha final

Si tienes un array con los munitus usarias

```
foreach (int i = 0; i < llegada.Length; i++)
{
    horactual = horactual.AddMinutes(llegada[i]);
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = horactual.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Lo que trato de hacer es lo siguiente, en mi Array tengo varios numeros almacenados, contiene los numeros de 30,60,90 y asi sucesivamente. Ahora tengo una hora que son las 10:00:00 cuando sale el primer valor del Array es 30 y ahora el valor de las hora es 10:30:00, despues necesito que a las 10:30:00 se le sumen el siguien te valor que es 60, lo cual seria las 12:30:00. Espero me puedas ayudar por favor

Comment: pero entonces no tiendo cual es el problema, edite el ejemplo usando el array que mencionas

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, el Array es que esta como llegada[i]. Lo unico que necesito es que el primer numero del array se le sume a la hora, despues que la hora se actualice (ejemplo de 10:00:00 - 10:30:00), despues pase de (10:30:00-10:45:00) ya que los numeros que se agregan nunca van de 30 en 30, puede ser de 15, 30, 25, 140, ect.

Comment: pero analizaste bien el segundo codigo que puse? porque justamente lo que haces es ir sumando los minutos de array, solo que para que se sume debes ir poniendo el resultado sobre la misma variable

Comment: Perdon, no habia visto tu segundo codigo, el cual me sirvio perfectamente. Una disculpa, y muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Puedo hacerte otra pregunta? ¿O la publico como una nueva pregunta?

Comment: depende la pregunta, si esta relacionada puedes hacerla, si es algo my distinto seria mejor generar otra pregunta